# Does a C program in linux get a PID?

Tags: c, linux, process

I have a simple C program and when I compile and run it with `./output`, does it get a PID on Linux? (I think, every running program is a process and it should have a PID.)

I used the `ps aux` command but I couldn't find the process name there.

I remember, when my console application (a C program) was running on Windows 7, I was able to get its PID via the Volatility tool.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("Hello World!");
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, every running program on Linux gets a PID.

Your program just prints `"Hello, World!"`, and will complete so quickly that by the time you run `ps aux` it will have finished.

Also, `void main()` should be `int main(void)`, and you should add `\n` to the end of your output string.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. One follow up question: when this program terminates, does its data (suppose there are some global, static and local variables ) also get wiped from memory? Thanks.

Comment: It's obviously no longer accessible by the program, since the program is no longer running. Depending on the system, the bits might still be there, but there's no easy way to access them. Or the system might erase the memory that was used by the program. The use of virtual memory complicates this; a given address in one program is not the same piece of physical memory as the same address in another program. Summary: Practically speaking, no; technically speaking, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

It should. just printf getpid() in you program to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Or just add a sleep so that you can find the process ID. Probably ran whilst you blinked.

Use this code and in a separate terminal run `ps`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  sleep(3600);
  printf("Are you bored yet?\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it using getpid

```
int main()
{
    pid_t pid; 
    printf("Hello World!");
    printf("pid of program is %d" , getpid());   
}
```

or just use your code and put it into background.

```
void main()
{
    printf("Hello World!");
}
```

Output:

```
[xxxxx@localhost ~]$ ./c1 &
[1] 3007
3007
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, every process gets a PID while it is being run. Since this C program seems to a very short-lived process, it might be completing before you could even run your `ps aux` command to get its PID. Try calling `getchar()` or a `scanf()` that would wait for user input and then run the ps command from a different terminal to see the PID.

Comment: getch is not there in linux :-) , for using that u need to have ncurses library

Comment: Thanks @AkhilThayyil, corrected the answer to use some user-input function :)

Comment: The `getch()` function provided by ncurses is not the same as the `getch()` function on Windows.